# Uploading an XML file onto Amazon S3 without any downloads of programs

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

Background:
I intern at a company where installing new software is a major hassle since it needs to go through a metric ****ton of security and approvals. I am very new to shell scripting and need a lot of help.

I need to write a script to upload an XML file onto Amazon S3. The solution should not require any downloads of any extra files or programs and hopefully work on a UNIX VM. Is this possible or is the only solution to download their CLI.

edit:
https://gist.github.com/chrismdp/6c6b6c825b07f680e710
http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash
I don't know if this requires anything extra to be installed, but how would I modify the content type to be for an XML file?

Comment: One option: http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash

Comment: You can have a look at  https://gist.github.com/chrismdp/6c6b6c825b07f680e710

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file on S3 using following options:
1. Browser
2. Tools like s3cmd or aws cli.

If you are using "AWS AMI"; then AWS CLI is pre-installed.. If you are using something generic like Ubuntu ; how can you expect to integrate with AWS Services; when it has nothing ( no software ) specific to AWS.. This is not true with just this case; but in any case.. Whenever you need to interact with a third party; either you need to use browser or some sdk/library to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to interact with S3 using nothing but tools you probably already have, like curl or wget, and openssl... but it some requires effort, because you have to be able to sign the requests.  That is the complex part.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

I'm sure a lot of people have written their own implementations of this.  I know I have, and I like mine because it has a "close to the metal" feel about it that the SDKs lack.  I even wrote an implementation of this entirely in SQL (yes, I am serious, I wrote a MySQL stored function that generates S3 signed URLs).  If you are a solid programmer, it's not that difficult, though it can seem daunting.

The following is not a specific tool recommendation, but rather an example found from googling, and it looks usable:
https://github.com/wikiwi/s3-bash4 is a collection of a few bash scripts that string together curl (for web requests), openssl (for its utility functions, like HMAC digests) and shasum (they could have used openssl for this, too) -- tools you should already have -- and can interact with S3.

You don't have to download or install anything, just write your own derivative using this as a starting point.